# how can I change the lowercase array values to uppercase?

Tags: java

I need "args[i]" to be converted to Uppercase so the output will be:

> "$ARG1" line break
>   "$ARG2" line break
>   "$ARG3" line break

and so on. I need to use the "toUpperCase" method but don't know how.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Number of args:" +
           args.length);
        for(int i=0; i<args.length; i++){
            char dollar = '\u0024';
            System.out.println(dollar + args[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say you "don't know how" to call `toUpperCase()`?  You don't know how to call a method on an object?

Comment: You know that whether or not it will print ARG1 or something else depends on what you pass to the program as command line arguments. If you run your program as `java Main a b c` then you'll get `$A $B $C` (with line breaks). Also, isn't it simpler to use `'$'` rather than `'\u0024'`?

Comment: yes  dear ..exactly:)

Comment: RealSkeptic got iit ! haha actually I needed to have some practice with unicodes.. I'm a beginner :D..thx

Comment: See related answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320200/turn-a-user-input-string-to-upper-case-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365728/java-how-do-you-convert-lower-case-string-values-to-upper-case-ones-in-a-string

Comment: very cool !  I'll check it out!

Comment: Why does this have 7 upvotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

java has String method :public String toUpperCase()

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Number of args:" + args.length);

        for(int i=0; i<args.length; i++){
            char dollar = '\u0024';
            System.out.println(dollar + args[i].toUpperCase());
        }

    } 
}
```

See the Oracle documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase())

Answer (score 5):

Java has this functionality built into the `String` object like so:

```
 System.out.println(dollar + args[i].toUpperCase());
```

See the Oracle documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase())

Answer (score 4):

Just use `.toUpperCase()` on any `String`, and it will return an all-upper-case `String`.

```
System.out.println(dollar + args[i].toUpperCase());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Number of args:" +
           args.length);
        char dollar = '\u0024';
        for(int i=0; i<args.length; i++){
            System.out.println(dollar + args[i].toUpperCase());
        }
    }
}
```